# Can I redirect output to a log file and background a process at the same time?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

Can I redirect output to a log file and a background process at the same time?

In other words, can I do something like this?

```
nohup java -jar myProgram.jar 2>&1 > output.log &
```

Or, is that not a legal command?  Or, do I need to manually move it to the background, like this:

```
java -jar myProgram.jar 2>$1 > output.log
jobs
[CTRL-Z]
bg 1
```

Comment: Have you tried it? What error do you get? Also I'm not sure if you have a typo, or an error in your code. `2>$1` is probably supposed to be `2>&1`.

Answer (score 298, accepted):

One problem with your first command is that you redirect stderr to where stdout is (if you changed the $ to a & as suggested in the comment) and then, you redirected stdout to some log file, but that does not pull along the redirected stderr. You must do it in the other order, first send stdout to where you want it to go, and then send stderr to the address stdout is at

```
some_cmd > some_file 2>&1 &
```

and then you could throw the & on to send it to the background. Jobs can be accessed with the `jobs` command. `jobs` will show you the running jobs, and number them. You could then talk about the jobs using a % followed by the number like `kill %1` or so.

Also, without the & on the end you can suspend the command with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>z</kbd>, use the `bg` command to put it in the background and `fg` to bring it back to the foreground.  In combination with the `jobs` command, this is powerful.

to clarify the above part about the order you write the commands. Suppose stderr is address 1002, stdout is address 1001, and the file is 1008. The command reads left to right, so the first thing it sees in yours is `2>&1` which moves stderr to the address 1001, it then sees `> file` which moves stdout to 1008, but keeps stderr at 1001. It does not pull everything pointing at 1001 and move it to 1008, but simply references stdout and moves it to the file.
The other way around, it moves stdout to 1008, and then moves stderr to the point that stdout is pointing to, 1008 as well. This way both can point to the single file.

Comment: can't seem to capture the pid after this though with `$!`

Comment: Also worth noting: you can use `&> file.out` to redirect both stdin and stdout to an output file, which cuts down on the possibility of a mistake with putting `2>&1` in the wrong place in your command line.

Comment: so it's better to use just ```cmd &> log.txt &``` ?

Comment: is this going to overwrite the existing log file? should we be doing `>>` instead of `>` to append to a log file?

Answer (score 59):

```
java -jar myProgram.jar &> output.log &
```

Note that the `&>` directs both stdout and stderr to output.log

Comment: A one-line explanation will make the answer complete.

Comment: @abhisheknaik96 it runs the jar file and redirects both stdin and stderr to output.log and make it background process.

Answer (score 18):

Stopping with `<Ctrl+Z>` and continuing in the background with `bg` is equivalent to execute with `&` at the end of the command.

So, for run in the background and redirect output:

```
java -jar myProgram.jar 2> errorOutput.log > output.log &
```

If you also need that this command does not die when you leave the terminal, then you should use `nohup`

Comment: Oh I see.  You are saying the appended '&' char is redundant?

Comment: I just quote the manpage. Since nohup will execute the command in the background anyway, seems redundant to execute nohup itself in the background

Comment: nohup doesn't execute the command in the background, you have to explicitly append `&`

Comment: After you moved a process to the background with `bg`, you can detach it from your session by running `disown`, which makes that the process doesn't die when you close the terminal.

Answer (score 12):

The `tee` command is pretty prevalent too.

`nohup java -jar myProgram.jar | tee output.log &`

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using nohup you can use screen. You can view the status of the program in real time. you can even log all the output to a file. It is useful when you access the server via ssh where you get logged out due to poor connection or inactivity. After logging in you can continue the work from where you left. refer [this](https://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/) and [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) to know in detail.

Answer (score 2):

```
java -jar myProgram.jar &> output.log & disown
```

By `&>` you can write both `stdout` and `stderr` to a file. Latter `&` sends this process to the background, and `disown` makes this task independent from the terminal. Now you can even close the terminal.